# angular - changing data in assets folder of the build

Tags: angular, assets

I want my angular app to work as a Standalone without a server.

In the assets folder are images, sound-files etc. and one *game.json* file which contains the business data for the application (On a server this data would be stored in a DB or would be called via Rest).

Everything works quite well. Using 'ng build' I can create the complete build which can be startet by opening the index.html in my OS - file manager without a http-Server.

The problem is that I can't change the content of *game.json* **after** the build, because it seems to be included in the build in some way. Changes are ignored, it freezes the content in state it was compiled.

Since I will run the app only locally I read my data this way:

**typings.d.ts:**

```
declare module "*.json" {
   const value: any;
   export default value;
 }
```

**game.service.ts:**

```
import * as data_json from 'assets/data/game.json';

@Injectable()
export class GameService {

  constructor() { }
      loadGames(): Observable<Game> {
        return Observable.of(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data_json)));
      }
}
```

I don't use HTTPClient because I would run into CORS problems.
Reading the data works fine, but changes in the file game.json are ignored completely.

Is there a way to make this file "modifyable" so I can change it in the assets folder of the build?

Comment: Why you don't want to use HTTPClient  to get data from assets folder? I don't think you will have any issue related to CORS if you it.

Comment: I tried to, but I ran into CORS issues.

Comment: You can try my solution mentioned below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get data from assets folder like shown below and you can also change it run time.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class GameService {
  private gameData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  loadGameData() {
    return this.http
      .get("/assets/data/game.json")
      .toPromise()
      .then(data => {
        this.gameData= data;
      });
  }

  get gameData() {
    if (!this.gameData) {
      throw Error("Game file not loaded!");
    }
    return this.gameData;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts changes:

```
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from "@angular/core";
import { GameService } from "./services/GameService.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    [
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        multi: true,
        deps: [GameService],
        useFactory: (gameService: GameService) => {
          return () => {
            return gameService.loadGameData();
          };
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: I use angular 5. so there is no 'providedIn' property in the annotation.

I marked the service with Injectable and added the provider part in game.module.ts. I removed the providers in the comp.
-> Exception: 
  StaticInjectorError()[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> GameService]: NullInjectorError: No provider for GameService!

If I add the service to the provider part in the component, it does not work either

Comment: provide GameService in app module providers above APP_INITIALIZER code , it will work.

Comment: I did. GameService is as you suggested. app.module.ts now contains the APP_INITIALIZER - provider with deps and factory, etc. The comp. that uses the service is in submodule game.module.ts. Do I have to register the service in the comp. or the module as well? Or is the service accessable "from root". i.e. generally from everywhere?