# create a file for http call errors

Tags: angular

```
 handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log('all');
    const blob = new Blob(['Hello, world!'], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'hello world.txt');
    return throwError(error);
  }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request)
      .pipe(
        retry(1),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

Here is interceptor call and I want to create a file and append all data error data into same file as many errors occurs.

I tried `FileSaver` but it downloads the file and I need create a file in assets folder for all recurring error logs.

Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296737/angular-changing-data-in-assets-folder-of-the-build

Comment: How does it write the file back. Please a short explanation